# How does device A knows that device B is in the same network without static IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip

Hello i would like to know how do devices in the same network find each other, without knowing the IP address of course. What is the system or pocess called.

Several example of this are:

I have a portable router that uses LTE from my cellular provider to create a portable wifi network, this router comes with a optional downloadable app that lets me top up load or register promos. This app usually requires a sign in BUT when i am connected to the network of the router is automatically detects that i am connected to my specific router.

Another would be wireless printers. where in if i want to print something i can just "search" for a printer in the network. Of course the printer does not have a static ip and all it needs is to be connected in the same network.

last of my examples is one of those smart devices, but this is an oddball because it needs to be paired beforehand and after that you can see it in the network, again they are not assigned to static IPs

My goal would be to learn how this system works so that i could replicate this feature on a project i am working with.

Comment: Depending on the network layer it may be by: ARP, the IP subnet broadcast address, or a multicast address. Learning material recommendations are off-topic here. Using those examples in Google searches should yield more than you wanted to know.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart which would be the simpliest to use? hopefully with no additional hardware required and can be easily recreatable by just coding.

Comment: Your subject question and your remaining questions are not really the same at all... How does device A know that device B is in the same network without a static IP? The same way even if they did have static IP's, because of the subnet mask. How does device A find a SPECIFIC device B in the same network? That could be any of the methods @Tim_Stewart mentioned, and DNS, Netbios, or any host of other special means. If you are looking for learning materials and not SPECIFIC answers though, this is not the forum for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a wide variety of discovery-oriented services that make up modern networks, each targeting a specific technical problem and scope, so there is no one answer to your question, many technologies stack upon eachother vertically, and we can't tell you about every technology in play (and you wouldn't want us to, this is a common problem, and the solutions are legion).

For low level networking, on networks like ethernet, ARP tables and broadcast resolution are common. [Token Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_ring), [Fiberchannel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel), and other common network layers use their own schemes. At this layer, the only distinguishing feature of an endpoint is its hardware address, so you must know it in order to reach another endpoint.

For TCP/IP layer, service advertisement and discovery protocols are contained in technologies like [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)), [AVAHI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)), and [WS-Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#WS-Discovery). Many services provide their own discoverability like SMB/NetBIOS, which is often how printers advertise their services over windows networks.

Naming assists in service discovery at many levels. SMB hosts maintain lists of name-IP maps that they pass around, and many services use [DNS Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) to indicate endpoints.  Directories like [Active Director](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) of [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) host queryable databases containing information on where to find things.

and many more...

As you can see, you have to define the scope of the problem you are trying to work on in order to pick the right technologies for your usecase. There are lots of options out there.

Comment: I did not know it was this broad, all i wanted to do was for me to be able to find another device on the same local network, my first idea was to do a GET request on all 256 addresses in the network. I was certain that was a very brute way of doing it thus me asking the question of how is it done in devices that does it. But the common method in the one you mention and in the comments is multicast address, There also sample codes that does this in my platform which is a good indicator that this might be what im looking for

Comment: so your scope is TCP/IP layer service discovery, and it sounds like you want it to be decentralized (no central database of endpoints like DNS, LDAP, etc). your general idea isn't too far off, but the details are unsound. Broadcast is a good simple way to go, and multicast is great if you are willing to deal with the added complexity, but I do caution you to keep your architecture at the highest layer you can, and consider using existing service discovery frameworks like WS-Discovery to abstract away the details of the discovery scheme from your code.

Comment: on the three frameworks you mentions all have libraries in my platform which is great !! which of the three do you recommend most?

Comment: I believe WS-Discovery would work with the broadest range of platforms and stacks, but you have to pick an implementation of it. if you are using windows+.net all the WSDL tools are there, but for other platforms you'll look at whats available. I'd look at what others on your particular stack are using.